# use case steps and use case scenrios

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I am modelling a system and i have the following are some of my use cases{appoint teacher(adimin),record grades(teacher), manage students(admin),record attendance(teacher), manage cocurricular(admin)}
I have some problems with coming up with use case steps and use case scenarios.
i have already drawn my conceptual class diagram.
does any one have an idea on how to go about that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You may find an article such as [this](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/systemUseCase.htm) useful.

My way of thinking. You have general description of the use cases, so you know what the system you're building is supposed to do. But those use cases no doubt have lots of wrinkles and special cases. [In passing "Manage Students" seems at a rather different granularity from "Appoint Teacher" susepect you need "Enrol Student", "Suspend Student", "Graduate Student" or some such.]

So your next step is to capture more of the requirements of the system by giving  more detail of the use cases. You express that in terms of actions by people and systems. Do you have a system context diagram or some such? This would show everything your system interacts with. You then express your scenarios as a sequence of actions by actors, your system and other systems.

```
The Teacher logs on
TheSystem presents a menu
The Teacher selects "record grade"
The System presents a list of classes taught by the teacher
The Teacher selects class
etc.
```

The wrinkles come from considering the variations that might occur. Any special actions for failing grades? Restrictions on grading for certain types of students? So you create additional scenarios for such "interesting" cases.

In my understanding, at this stage specfic classes and class diagrams are not needed. Later you can consider one step such as "The system presents a list of classes taugh by the teacher" and consider how the system implements that using your class diagram.

Remember the objective here: get the complete picture of the requirements you need to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, although you may not need to do this in class (sounds like a class you're taking), another useful step in requirements gathering is identifying the misuse cases. That is, you want to figure out what bad things could happen in your system. For example, a misuse case could be someone hacking into the system, and then you could write out the steps you would take to correct such a misuse case. Just something to think about.